# Why stat64() in linux becomes slower as the number of files in a directory increases?

Tags: c, linux, fat

I run `stat64()` for 1000 files in a folder and took less than 1s but when there were 5000 in the same directory, the time increased to `15s`.

Why `stat64 ()` is getting slow non -linearly ? I was expecting the time to be 5s

**EDIT**
I am reading data from a USB with FAT file system.

Comment: Because you are using a toy file system which is scanning the list of entries for every name lookup. Try XFS (best) or ext4 or enabling "dir_index" on ext3.

Comment: what's your file system type?

Comment: @Insane Coder: Are you stat64-ing 1000 files in both cases or are you stat64-ing every file that is present?

Comment: @WernerHenze : Every file that is present. In first case for 1000 files and in second case for 5000 files.

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling `stat64` for a file in a directory which contains N entries, then the complexity is O(N) because with FAT file system the system has to walk through all directory entries and compare each to the one you are looking for.

When you are calling `stat64` M times in a folder which contains N entries, then the complexity is O(M*N) and in the case there M=N you end up with O(N*N).

Looking at your example: when you have and `stat64` factor 5 files, then you need factor 25 time. If your 1s time in fact was 0.6 seconds, then the results are as expected.